# Handling custom __new__() and __del__() with inheritance

Tags: python

When I derive a class in Python, I need to call the `Base.__init__(self)` from the derived `__init__(self)` function like

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Der(Base):
    def __init__(self) :
        Base.__init__(self)
```

Do I need to do the same for `__new__(self)` and `__del__(self)` functions like

```
class Base(object):
    def __new__(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        pass    
    def __del__(self) :
        pass

class Der(Base):
    def __new__(self):
        Base.__new__(self)

    def __init__(self) :
        Base.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self) :
        Base.__del__(self)
```

I am wondering because nothing seems to go WRONG if I don't do that. 
I am sure that python `gc` will take care, but is there anything I need to be worried about if I don't call them from Derived chain

Comment: You don't actually need to implement *any* of those methods. Only override methods where the child behaviour is *different* to its parent; otherwise, just let the parent method get called directly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The usage of `__init__()` and `__del()` is straightforward but not the `__new()__`

Since `__new()__`  returns an instance of the class, we need to call `super().__new()__` till the object chain as given below

```
class Base(object):
    def __new__(self):
        return super().__new__(self)

class Derive(Base):
    def __new__(self):
        return super().__new__(self);
```

The `__del()__` can be using similar to `__init()__`, calling `Base.__del()__` is not mandatory unless and until some cleanup is required in base `__del()` function.

The correct way of writing the code asked in the question is

```
class Base(object):
    def __new__(self):
         return super().__new__(self)

    def __init__(self):
        self.Value = 200

    def __del__(self):
        pass


class Derive(Base):
    def __new__(self):
        return super().__new__(self);

    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        Base.__del__(self)
```

It's always better not to implement `__new()__` and `__del()__` unless we really need it